# Get item when is hidden with *ngIf in Angular for test

Tags: angular, jasmine

#### My HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="state"> 
  <p>some text<p>
  <button (click)="increment()" class="myButton">Increment</button>
</div>
```

#### There is my component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  state = false;
  counter = 0;
  constructor(private app: AppService, private http: HttpClient, private 
    router: Router
  ) {}
  increment() {
    this.counter += 1;
  }
```

#### There is my beforeEach where I change my variable state to true and after I call detectChanges()

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AppService,
        { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub},
        { provide: HttpClient, useClass: HttpClientStub},
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.state = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

#### When I test the btn is undefined

```
it ('should increment by 1', () => {
  const btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.myButton')).nativeElement;
  // When I console.log(btn) here the btn is null because the state was false at begining;
  btn.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.counter).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: Really you don't need to test if the button clicking works. Just test that the counter gets incremented when you call the increment() function.

Comment: When i try to  trigger the click on the button jasmine tell me ( Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null  )

Comment: You don't really **need** to test the click aspect. Just that the increment() does what it should when it gets clicked. I can write an answer to show you how to do that if you want?

Comment: The question isn't about this example but for all my app.
For example if I want to check something inside a block with ngIf inside my HMTL 
ex: I have a text which use a variable and I want to know if nobody delete my text from html how can I do that?

Comment: I have looked over the code a couple of times now, it should work as far as I could tell. Could you post your component .ts file as well? And the rest of your HTML if there is more?

Comment: @SnorreDan I changed my post,  added my component

Comment: Well I do see that your component.ts file is named "AppComponent", while the component you are testing is called "TestComponent", but I am guessing you changed the names just before you posted here on StackOverflow? If that is not the problem, then I still don't know why this doen't work.

Comment: yes is a mistake, anyway thanks for your help @SnorreDan

Answer (score 0):

This should be working. I was going to write this as a comment but I needed space.

Try:

```
it ('should increment by 1', () => {
  console.log(component.state);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  console.log(component.state);
  expect(state).toBe(true);
  console.log(fixture.nativeElement);
  const button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button.myButton');
  console.log(button);
});
```

I will edit my answer to hopefully get what you want. Can you tell me what those logs output?

Comment: console.log(component.state);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log(component.state);
    expect(component.state).toBe(true);
    const de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.myButton'));
    console.log(de);

log is null

Comment: I have edited my answer, can you see `fixture.nativeElement` and make sure the `button.myButton` is in the log? Also, can you see the log of `button`?

Answer (score 0):

So if someone wants to access something inside html when is hidden by ngIf you should import your component in declarations inside your TesteBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [YourComponent]}) that's it.